# get golang interface name dynamically

Tags: reflection, go, interface

I have a interface:

```
type Printer interface {
    Print(s string)
}
```

and a func:

```
func fxyz(name string) {
    ....
}
```

I want to call fxyz with "Printer", but I don't want to hard code the string.

How could I get the Interface Name using reflection or other approach?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want exactly?

Comment: If I understand well, OP wants an implementation of Print to call fxyz passing the name of the interface as the name parameter... well, even then that does not seem much clearer... Using reflection for this would be an unacceptable tradeoff for simply using the "Printer" string constant, since Print will always be an implementation of the Printer interface anyways...

Comment: I think icza was asking more about 'why' - that is, people often ask how to solve a specific issue rather than whether that is even the right approach. Dynamically calling interfaces in Go like this is very likely to be the wrong approach.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get the name of the interface, you can do that using `reflect`:

```
name := reflect.TypeOf((*Printer)(nil)).Elem().Name()
fxyz(name)
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Lv6-qqqQsH.

Note, you cannot just take `reflect.TypeOf(Printer(nil)).Name()` because `TypeOf` will return `nil`.